# Generate const for VisualStudio SQL project

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, project

I have a **.NET web application** using **C#** and **SQL Server** for the database part. Recently I found out about the "SQL Server Database Project" in VisualStudio to add my SQL schema into my CVS. Very helpful! Besides, if I make some mistake in a stored procedure for example, the solution won't build, which is awesome.

Now, my problem. I have some dozens of stored procedures in my DB. In the C# part, I group the stored procedures calls in classes, where I write something similar to: `ExecuteQuery("spMyStoredProcedure", SqlParamenter[]...)`. As you see, I kind of hardcode the stored procedure name. A better option would be to create constants like:

```
private static const string SP_MY_STORED_PROCEDURE = "spMyStoredProcedure";
```

But as I only use the stored procedure once, it's almost the same as hard-coding. What would be really nice is to generate those constants (stored procedures names, parameters, table names, columns, etc) from the SQL Server Project. Actually, it would be even better if it generates code automatically, to call those stored procedures like C# methods, but constants are good enough for me :). It would be nice if I could rename stored procedures in my SQL-Server-Project so visual studio changes my C# code properly, or show build errors in a SP call if I remove a parameter from the stored procedure.

I know that, in Visual Studio, the SQL project generates a DLL file, but if I inspect it is empty, so I can't just add a reference into my C# project. I have spent hours and hours googling for it and looking in SO, but found nothing. I just cannot believe that nobody else tried to do such a simple thing before. It looks so natural to me, and implement such a functionality should be a piece of cake for Microsoft, right?. Am I missing something here? How would you solve this?

Comment: My immediate knee-jerk reaction to what you want is "don't do it, what you have works perfectly". Having the db project is cool and everything, but don't try to over-simplify/optomize/automate (introducing more complexity) your current code. Having them in consts won't help anyone trying to take over your work/work on the same project as you unless they know very specifically what/where to look for it. Especially when trying to figure out which stored procedure is called where to debug. I won't call what you are doing "hard coding". I'd have called it that if you had actual SQL in your code

Comment: I agree with you, partially. I always say, if it works, don't change it if is not for a good reason. In this case, the change would be minimal: is just change the "hardcoded" strings with a constant, so it "can't" actually break anything (the actual code remains the same, and probably the constant would have the same name as the value). My idea would be to have those constants in a separated file, generated (and updated) automatically by visual studio. Besides, the stored procedures will change in the future, so it would be nice to have a safe net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the exciting T4 files that can generate the code for us!

You can set up a `.tt` file that can search in the folder where you keep your stored procedures, extract the list of files, strip the `.sql` extension from the file names, and iterate through this list to generate constant variables. Slick!

So in one of your c# projects from your solution (preferably the Database one, if you have a layered application architecture) add a **StoredProceduresNames.tt** file that will contain the following T4 code:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".generated.cs" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
namespace MyProject.Constants {

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the names of the stored procedures of the application
    /// </summary>
    public static class StoredProceduresNames 
    {
<# 
    string storedProceduresFolder = "Stored Procedures"; //set the path to sp folder here...
    string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(Host.ResolvePath(storedProceduresFolder));
    foreach(var filePath in fileArray){
        string spName = Path.GetFileName(filePath).ToUpper().Replace(".SQL", "");       
#>
        public const string <#= spName #> = "<#= spName #>";
<#
        }
 #>
    }
}
```

You might want to set the variable `storedProceduresFolder` relatively to the `.tt` file (I mean, if the .tt file is in a c# project and your stored procedures are in database project, the path should be something like `../MyProject.Database/Stored Procedures`.

You can then use the generated file in your code:

```
ExecuteQuery(MyProject.StoredProceduresNames.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE, SqlParamenter[]...)
```

Feel free to tweak this code as you need (code conventions, comments, etc.)

**UPDATED: consider using Entity Framework for code generation**

You can also try to let Entity Framework to generate the code for you, not only for the tables, but also for calling stored procedures. Check out [this article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/calling-stored-procedures-from-entity-framework.aspx) for more info, using Entity Framework you can call your stored procedures in this manner:

```
MyEntities context = new MyEntities();
context.CallMyStoredProcedure(123, "West");//call to stored procedure
```

Another benefit is that the result of the stored procedures is also strongly typed.

Comment: That's a very cool solution. Thank you! I didn't knew about text templates. It works like a charm for stored procedures (I only had to tweak a little tiny bit), but there is no easy way to do the same for the SP parameters: I would have to parse the SQL file! So, my problem is still half solved.

Comment: Cool! I just got a crazy idea: what if instead of reading the names of the stored procedures we call a stored procedure directly to on the db server, on the master database, and retrieve the metadata for each stored procedure containing not only the name of each stored procedure, but also the name of its parameters. We can then generate also the parameter names in the code!

Comment: Mmm interesting. I didn't thought about that. If I don't find another solution, I will give it a try. But it seems a bit too complicated to me. Shouldn't be that info inside the DLL file generated by the project? Can I assume there is no other, easier, way? Every other project in the world uses AdHoc names for tables, columns, sp, parameters, etc. embedded inside the code?

Comment: There might be other ways. I do not have too many knowledges about the generated DLL and what is it's use. Regarding the AdHoc names I think right now not many people are concerned with this. Since Entity Framework makes a good job, I find myself calling stored procedures more rarely and only for very complex queries that cannot be handled by EF. Less stored procedures, less hardcoded strings...

Comment: @JoséRamón Hi, Check out my update of using EF for generating the code for you. Hope this solves your issue :).

Comment: Ok, looks like that ADO.NET is what I was looking for: an abstraction layer between the database and my code. Although we can't migrate the project to EF right now, I will have a look. Thanks @Lucian!